# Increase font size and Properties in X11 R6

Tags: c++, linux, x11, embedded-linux, xlib

I am using X11 R6 to write text using XDrawString() .In this i can't increase the font size and i don't know how to use superscript  and subscript.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't use `XDrawString` these days fonts are dealt in the client, not the server. And use some toolkit above X11: Qt, GTk, FLTK, FOX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is related to the GC, so you have to change it there when using XDrawString.

XDrawText is easier, you give it a list of XTextItems which can each have their own font.

For superscripts and subscripts, it is up to you to position the text.  You can get the correct positions by looking at the XA_SUPERSCRIPT_X, XA_SUPERSCRIPT_Y, XA_SUBSCRIPT_X and XA_SUBSCRIPT_Y atoms with XGetFontProperty.